# how to convert tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm to tf2.0

Tags: tensorflow, version, tensorflow2.0, batch-normalization

I am converting the following code

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

def conv_layer(input_tensor,name,kernel_size,output_channels,initializer=tf.keras.initializers.VarianceScaling,stride=1,bn=False,training=False,relu=True):
    input_channels = input_tensor.get_shape().as_list()[-1]
    with tf.variable_scope(name) as scope:
        kernel = variable('weights', [kernel_size, kernel_size, input_channels, output_channels], initializer, regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.0005))
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input_tensor, kernel, [1, stride, stride, 1], padding='SAME')
        biases = variable('biases', [output_channels], tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
        conv_layer = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
        if bn:
            conv_layer = batch_norm_layer(conv_layer,scope,training)
        if relu:
            conv_layer = tf.nn.relu(conv_layer, name=scope.name)

    return conv_layer

def batch_norm_layer(input_tensor,scope,training):
    return tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(input_tensor,scope=scope,is_training=training,decay=0.99)
```

I tried to convert

```
tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(input_tensor,scope=scope,is_training=training,decay=0.99)
```

with

```
tf.layers.batch_normalization(input_tensor, scope=scope, training=training, decay=0.99)
```

But I get the following error

```
TypeError: batch_normalization() got an unexpected keyword argument 'scope'
```

My question is : **How can I convert tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm with scope correctly?**

Answer (score 0):

Based on a review of the TF 1.15 API [r1.15/api_docs batch_norm](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/batch_norm)
and the v1-compat version [current api_docs for compat/v1/layers/batch_normalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/layers/batch_normalization)
the most likely substitute for the old **scope** parameter I can see is the **name** parameter.

So you might try rewriting your new code as:

```
tf.layers.batch_normalization(input_tensor, name=scope, training=training, decay=0.99)
```